# Saber se a scroll chegou ao fim da DIV

Tags: jquery

Como faço para saber que o usuário rolou a barra de scroll de uma `div` até o final? usando jquery.

Até agora só consegui isso

```
scrollTop();
```

mas não sei como esse comando pode me ajudar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').bind('scroll', function() {
        /*
        * scrollTop -> Quanto rolou
        * innerHeight -> Altura do interior da div
        * scrollHeight -> Altura do conteúdo da div
        */
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
            $('body').append("<p>Fim da div</p>");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div{
    height: 150px;
    width: 80px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>TESTE</p>
    <p>TESTE</p>
    <p>TESTE</p>
    <p>TESTE</p>
    <p>TESTE</p>
    <p>TESTE</p>
    <p>TESTE</p>
    <p>TESTE</p>
</div>
```

**[Fonte: Resposta SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271237/detecting-when-user-scrolls-to-bottom-of-div-with-jquery)**

Comment: Isso isso!! Demais! muchas gracias!! :D